# How to send variables from gis addin own web browser to gis file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, c#, php

I am a complete beginner with GIS.

So I want to be able to go to the coordinates in **arcmap** I fill in in my php page. I've got this now:

[image]

The variables inserted in the textfield should be the coordinates where I want to go to. The text inserted in X: and Y: are called $x and $y. How do I accomplish this?